# Time to stop unsubstantiated threats of closure?

Tags: discussion, scope, moderation

One member of our community is posting comments threatening closure of questions they don't believe are appropriate. I applaud the effort to improve the site, but the comments imply that community census on scope is immanent, which is far from the case.

> The meta post is under construction. The comment was a notice I left on all unqualified questions, so that users would have a fair amount of time to update their posts accordingly. As said, the post is under construction atm, and hasn't been finished yet. Feel free to propose improvements in chat. Thank you for your cooperation.

[How to cover nail holes effectively and inexpensively?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/164/how-to-cover-nail-holes-effectively-and-inexpensively#comment2527_164)

As we see in the comment left recently the user has not even written the post that they believe  "will shortly be ruled off-topic".  I am all for improving the site, and have no doubt that some of my posts are at past the ultimate scope of this site. But really have a problem with threaten a breach of a community accepted policy that only occurs as an incomplete thought in the posters imagination.

Comment: The post is written and in the final stages of editing. It will likely posted within the next 24 hours. We will gladly talk through the situation with you [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19330/the-junk-drawer) if you'd like.

Comment: Chat is not the place that community consensus is developed. You may be developing an idea in chat, but you need to post it to meta to get consensus.

Comment: As I said, the post will be posted on meta within the next 24 hours

Comment: So instead of making threats invite others to participate, in the comments to the questions.

Comment: Take a look at [what he's posting](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/261/im-in-the-rain-without-an-umbrella-how-can-i-get-home-quickly-without-getting#comment2326_261). That's not a threat, it's a statement of fact that helps the post be improved by clearly stating what is wrong

Comment: The comments are to help the site stay on-topic. If you think that maybe the comments could be reworded better, maybe you could do that?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I am not arguing that the post can be improved, I am arguing that statement "lack this basic information will shortly be ruled off-topic" is misleading at best.  You need to invite the community to participate in discussions, not mislead them. The community may or may not support the proposal you are working on, the only way to find out is to involve them.

Answer (score 7):

I've summarized everything that's been agreed upon in the previous Meta posts, and a few additions that have been discussed in chat, to make it clear what the scope of this site is. It wasn't ready to post because there was a lot to cover and I was away from my computer for a lot of the weekend.

The discussion in chat [started here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19038482#19038482), and the post is here: [The scope of Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/the-scope-of-lifehacks).

I'm assuming that those comments are just preemptive to the post so that the questions that are on the border of the scope can be edited to stay on the site, and don't get closed because of some minor technicality. The goal isn't to start from scratch, just to have some standards to apply to incoming questions so that we can have anyone on the site doing quality control without any deliberation.

To be clear, no one is being prevented from using chat, and participating in the discussion, and when the scope is posted, it's not going to be final. But it will ideally be something that doesn't require any large changes so that we can use it in order to keep the site from being closed.